# Cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to bool in Linq Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, where-clause

I guess this should be straight forward, but what is the correct way of filtering a related table in Linq to SQL. 
It works when I bring in the secondary table explicitely with a new join, but I'm sure filtering on the related table should also work.

For example:

```
var q = from p in db.Personnel
        where p.PersonnelGifts.Where(p => p.GiftValue >= 2477)
        select {...}
```

I get the error that

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

Comment: `where p.Gifts.Where(p => p.GiftValue >= 2477).Any()`?

Comment: Or even `where p.Gifts.Any(p => p.GiftValue >= 2477)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from p in db.Personnel
    where p.PersonnelGifts.Where(p => p.GiftValue >= 2477).Any()
    select {...}
```

or as @Jon Skeet pointed out - `.Any()` also accepts predicate, so you can write it like

```
var q = from p in db.Personnel
    where p.PersonnelGifts.Any(p => p.GiftValue >= 2477)
    select {...}
```

Why your code didn't work? `.Where()` returns `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable` for that matter) so you can chain it with another LINQ methods which accepts `IEnumerable` as parameter. Your `where` clause expects `bool` value and exactly this type is returned by `.Any()` method.